# Loop raster calculator QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator

Is there a way to loop raster calculator through a set of variables in QGIS model builder? (I realise I can do this in python)

Comment: What variables do you mean? Changing the formula in each loop?

Comment: Yes, (my_raster@1 >= [value to change]) * my_raster@1

Comment: In your model, you can add a `String` parameter and set this as the _Formula_ when you set up the Raster Calculator algorithm. Save the model then right-click it and select **Execute as batch process**. In the interface, you can define the number of loops, raster layer to use and the formula for each loop :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The model builder currently does not support loops.

As Joseph already commented, the alternative in Processing is to use the batch functionality.